# I am a bit confused on how to use datetime

Tags: python-3.x

I am running a simple code and I find myself to be a bit stuck. 
I've downloaded DateTime from DateTime. And for some reason, it won't work. I might be writing the DateTime wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

I might be writing the time wrong ive switched it from:

```
datetime.today().minute
```

to

```
datetime.datetime.now()
```

Code:

```
def headfirst_pg_4():

    odds = list(range(1,60, 2))

    right_minute = datetime.datetime.now()

    if right_minute in odds:
        print("This minute seems a little odd")
    else:
        print("Not an odd minute")
```

If its an odd number it will       print("This minute seems a little odd")
if its and even it will       print("Not an odd minute")

Comment: Do you know what the value of `right_minute` actually *is*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe well it was intended to get the number from the time.

Comment: Did you do any debugging to check whether that's what's happening?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes I've used pycharm debugging, and for some odd reason nothing would show up. If I print it out separately, it will print out the current time. I don't see any reason why it doesn't work. im a bit confused. :)

Comment: It does work, it's working perfectly; it's unclear why you thought a *datetime* would be in a list of *integers*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes now I understand. I must have overseen it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `right_minute = datetime.datetime.now()`

to

```
right_minute = datetime.datetime.now().minute
```

to get the current minute.

Comment: @ds007 please mark as the correct answer if it helped you :)

Comment: I'm new to StackOverflow how do I do that?

Comment: @ds007 Here is how to mark an answer as accepted - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers